# a phrasal verb about turning around something

Tags: meaning

What should we say to show someone rounds the building and goes to the back door? I mean the verb showing to turn around the building.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Could you please make your question clearer? If your question is a [single-word-request], please provide a sample sentence.

Answer (score 2):

**to move around**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/move+around) phrasal verb ( or **circle around** )

> pass to the other side of; "turn the corner"; "move around the
>   obstacle"

As in:

> He **moved around** the building to the back door.

Comment: This is not a phrasal verb, which is what was requested.

Comment: @tchrist edited tks

Comment: "*Circle around*" also works even if the movement is not perfectly circular; the aspect ratio of most buildings' footprint is on the order of 1:1.

Comment: @Chemomechanics tks - added

Answer (score 0):

I would    say 
'***to corner'.***

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corner:

***CORNER***

intransitive verb

: to turn a corner

// the car corners well

Comment: This is not a phrasal verb, which is what was requested